# Firebase Database and Storage project work does not work on real device (Android)

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I was working lately on Firebase Database, storage and Auth it works perfectly fine on Emulator however in real device I get "User does not have permission to access this object" when I upload an image, I tried changing the SHA1 to my console.firebase.google.com project/myProject-112f2/settings/general using SHA1 generated in keytool.exe -list from my local machine but still getting the same error. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one user in Authentication I thought since it works on emulator bypassing authentication direct to the activity which view the list and it works the same also with real device because I set my rules to

```
   "rules": {
     ".read": "auth === null",
     ".write": "auth === null"
  }
```

The emulator will work using this rules but the real device does not work you need to authenticate in order to execute READ and WRITE. By deleting the user from Authentication in console I can read and write. So firebase rules work Add user authenticate the user to execute read and write even if your rules are set to auth = null when using real device weird.

Answer (score 1):

**Read this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/secure-files#understand_rules) for more concept**

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/image-view-b1cf5.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      // Allow access by all users
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```